# Python - Intercept HTTP request from a page

Tags: python, http, flash, mechanize

Ok I've loaded an html page in python. For example using mechanize

```
 br = mechanize.Browser()
 br.open("http://www.example.com/")
```

Now I want to monitor his HTTP requests to intercept all the GET request made by an swf object embedded inside it. It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Mechanize does not do flash. Mechanize also has problems with javascript.

For this, you will probably want to do whatever automation directly in a full browser.